# How to conditional format and convert a dataframe to an image using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I want to conditional format a data frame and later convert it to an image.

Here is the base image and the specifications.

[image: Raw Data]

Specifications

- Column **key** is unaffected
- Column **base** has data bars
- Rest all columns (**c1 to c6**) are conditional formatted together (conditional formatting together is important i.e the max value among all these columns will have the darkest colour and the minimum one will have the lightest colour), zeroes are removed and values are converted to %
- Then this final dataframe should be converted to an image

[image: Final Dataframe]

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas `style` function, see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Background-Gradient-and-Text-Gradient):

```py
df.style.bar(subset="Base", color="#5fba7d").background_gradient(subset=["c1", "c2", "c3"])
```

I only used `c2/3` in my example because you didn't provide the code to create this `df` and I had to write it myself...
This gives you:

[image: Styled image output]

---

**Update**

```py
df.style.bar(subset="Base", color="#5fba7d").background_gradient(subset=["c1", "c2", "c3"], axis=None)
```

With using `axis=None` the background is applied to the whole subset, instead of just one column at a time.
See:

[image: Updated output]

---

**Update** using zeros as `np.nan`

```py
df[df.loc[:, ["c1", "c2", "c3"]] == 0] = np.nan
df.style.bar(subset="Base", color="#5fba7d").background_gradient(subset=["c1", "c2", "c3"], axis=None)
```

Gives:

[image: nan]

Comment: There is an issue in the image provided, c1,c2,c3 should be conditional formatted together, in the attached image c1 has different format, c2 has different and c3 has different format.
example :
0.13 is the largest in all three columns so it should have the darkest colour, but in c3 0.09 also has the same colour this should not be the case 0.09 should have a lower shade than 0.13

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly, using `axis=None` we can format it based on the whole subset.

Comment: This solved the issue, I have another issue related to this `df.export_png('df.png', table_conversion= 'chrome')` when I export the df using **table_conversion = 'chrome'** I get correct image with formatting, but with **matplotlib** the formatting is gone in the image, matplotlib is required in my case how can I solve it?

Comment: Also how do I remove the 0 cell values from image? I want to replace them with blanks

Comment: Unfortunately I never used the `dataframe_image` package, don't know how to fix the `matplotlib` issue, I'm sorry... However, if you liked my answer I'd appreciate it if you mark it as accepted

Comment: can you help me in removing 0 from the final data frame? how to replace them with blank in the final dataframe?

Comment: I don't think blank is possible, you can set all zeros to `np.nan` however... I update the answer

Comment: @Kundan If you find my answer helpful, I'd appreciate it if you accept it! Thank you